# PyTorch: How to get the shape of a Tensor as a list of int

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

In numpy, `V.shape` gives a tuple of ints of dimensions of V.

In tensorflow `V.get_shape().as_list()` gives a list of integers of the dimensions of V.

In pytorch, `V.size()` gives a size object, but how do I convert it to ints?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

For PyTorch v1.0 and possibly above:

```
>>> import torch
>>> var = torch.tensor([[1,0], [0,1]])

# Using .size function, returns a torch.Size object.
>>> var.size()
torch.Size([2, 2])
>>> type(var.size())
<class 'torch.Size'>

# Similarly, using .shape
>>> var.shape
torch.Size([2, 2])
>>> type(var.shape)
<class 'torch.Size'>
```

You can cast any torch.Size object to a native Python list:

```
>>> list(var.size())
[2, 2]
>>> type(list(var.size()))
<class 'list'>
```

---

In PyTorch v0.3 and 0.4:

Simply `list(var.size())`, e.g.:

```
>>> import torch
>>> from torch.autograd import Variable
>>> from torch import IntTensor
>>> var = Variable(IntTensor([[1,0],[0,1]]))

>>> var
Variable containing:
 1  0
 0  1
[torch.IntTensor of size 2x2]

>>> var.size()
torch.Size([2, 2])

>>> list(var.size())
[2, 2]
```

Comment: Instead of calling `list`, does the Size class have some sort of attribute I can access directly to get the shape in a tuple or list form?

Comment: You can access the size directly without casting it into a list. The OP requested for a list hence the type casting.

Comment: Useful input. Thanks. I can add one point. The result is still list form. We can write simply to get output as an integer:
`list(var.size())[0]` or `list(var.size())[1]`

Comment: The elements of `list(var.size())` have the type of `tensor` rather than `int` in my case. How to deal with it? I need `int`

Answer (score 14):

If you're a fan of `NumPy`ish syntax, then there's `tensor.shape`.

```
In [3]: ar = torch.rand(3, 3)

In [4]: ar.shape
Out[4]: torch.Size([3, 3])

# method-1
In [7]: list(ar.shape)
Out[7]: [3, 3]

# method-2
In [8]: [*ar.shape]
Out[8]: [3, 3]

# method-3
In [9]: [*ar.size()]
Out[9]: [3, 3]
```

**P.S.**: Note that `tensor.shape` is an alias to `tensor.size()`, though `tensor.shape` is an attribute of the tensor in question whereas `tensor.size()` is a function.

Comment: Which part of the code only works on a GPU machine? `tensor.shape`?

Answer (score 4):

A [`torch.Size`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/Size.cpp) object is [a subclass of `tuple`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html), and inherits its usual properties e.g. it can be indexed:

```py
v = torch.tensor([[1,2], [3,4]])
v.shape[0]
>>> 2
```

Note its entries are already of type `int`.

---

If you really want a list though, just use the `list` constructor as with any other iterable:

```py
list(v.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers got you list of torch.Size
Here is how to get list of ints

```
listofints = [int(x) for x in tensor.shape]
```